# Flutter: I want to center an element vertically but it won't work

Tags: flutter, alignment, center

I have a column with different rows and elements in it, now I want to center everything vertically.
I thought this would work with mainaxisalignment but it doesn't. In fact, no matter what I put in there, it doesn't change the layout. Wrapping it with Center widget doesnt do anything either. I don't know what to do about it :/

Working with a sizedbox with a fraction of mediaquery height gets it centered, if I calculate it correctly, but this is not ideal for me.

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("APP")),
  body: Column(
    children: [
    ElevatedButton
    (
      onPressed: () {
        
      }, child: Text("Hello")),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text("Hello"),
         ],
        )
      ]),
     );
   }
  }
```